# Handling no results redirect with Stash

Tags: stash, parse-order, redirects, no-results

This is more an A than a Q.

Last week I ran into no results / redirect problem with Stash and more precisely the EE's parsing order. The solution below worked for my case. I don't take credit for it as I found it either on the Devotee-forum for Stash or as a Gist someone was willing to share. I can't remember, after losing way to much time on this I didn't keep track. Anyway, thought I would share this as it may save others time.

On the template that collects the data...

```
{exp:stash:set 
parse_tags="yes" 
parse_conditionals="yes" 
parse_depth="2" 
no_results_prefix="nested"
}
    {exp:channel:entries 
    channel="YOURCHANNEL" 
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination" 
    status="open" 
    dynamic="no"
    }

        // channel entry data stuff here...

        {if nested:no_results}
            {exp:stash:set_value name="no_results" value="true"}
        {/if} 

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

{embed="YOURTEMPLATEGROUP/YOURTEMPLATE"}
```

Note: parse_depth and no_results_prefix Stash parameters are necessary.

On the embed that outputs the data (the view)

```
{if {exp:stash:not_empty name="no_results"}}
  {exp:stash:unset name="no_results"}
  {redirect="home/404"}
{/if}
```

Comment: May want to put this in question/answer format and answer your own question, marking it as answered.

Comment: Agreed this should be in Q/A format.  It has an answer and should not show up in unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question has been answered above, but hasn't yet been added as answer, I'll answer it here, so it can be marked as answered and corrected.

I ran into the same issue but solved it a little bit differently. Where the answer above redirects in the template, I did the redirection immediately in the template, rather than the embedded snippet. Like this:

```
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2" unprefix="detail"}
     {exp:channel:entries 
          channel="channel_entries" 
          status="open" 
          limit="1"       
          disable="pagination|member_data|categories|category_fields"          
          require_entry="yes"}

             {if detail:no_results}
                {redirect="404"}
             {/if}

     {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```